# How to generate multiple, slightly different XSD schemas from one Java model with JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I have a set of related Java classes, which are able to hold data I need. Below is a simplified class diagram of what I have:

[image]

Now I need to import data from XML and for that I want to generate XSD schema. The problem is that I want several XSD schemas like this:

1. One that allows the whole data graph to be imported.
2. One that allows only RootNote.fieldA and ChildNodeA.
3. One that allows only RootNote.fieldB and ChildNodeB.

I can easily generate XSD that meets the requirements of nr.1 using JAXB (programmatically). But is there a way to do that for cases nr.2 and nr.3 for the same classes? In other words, it seems I need something like "profiles" in JAXB.

**Update:**

Here is how I generate XSD schema:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(RootNode.class);

final File baseDir = new File(".");

class MySchemaOutputResolver extends SchemaOutputResolver {
  public Result createOutput( String namespaceUri, String suggestedFileName ) throws IOException {
    return new StreamResult(new File(baseDir,suggestedFileName));
  }
}

jc.generateSchema(new MySchemaOutputResolver());
```

Comment: Would you please post a snippet of code on how you generate your schema? Would be a very good complimentary. Some people may find an answer to their question in your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer, just an idea.

You probably use the `javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.generateSchema(SchemaOutputResolver)` method to generate your schema, so you basically use a specific `JAXBContext` instance. This instance is built based on the annotations in classes. When building the context, these annotations are read an organized into a model which is then used for all the operations.

So to generate different schemas you probably need to create different contexts. You can't change the annotations per case, but you can *read* annotations in different ways.

Take a look at the [AnnotationReader](https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxb/blob/3461152ffe39baf32b8550d47d18d58cdbc139c5/jaxb-ri/core/src/main/java/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/annotation/AnnotationReader.java). This is what JAXB RI uses behind the scenes to load annotations from Java classes. You can create your own implementation and use it when creating the JAXBContext. Here's an [example of something similar](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/ANX/JAXB+User+Guide):

```
final AnnotationReader<Type, Class, Field, Method> annotationReader = new AnnoxAnnotationReader();

final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

properties.put(JAXBRIContext.ANNOTATION_READER, annotationReader);

final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(
    "org.jvnet.annox.samples.po",
    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(),
    properties);
```

So how about writing your own annotation reader, which would consider what you call "profiles"? You can invent your own annotation `@XmlSchemaProfile(name="foo")`. Your annotation reader would then check if this annotation is present with the desired value and then either return it or ignore it. You'll be able to build different contexts from the same Java model - and consequently produce different schemas according to profiles defined by your `@XmlSchemaProfile` annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that suited me. The idea is to output the result of XSD generation into an XML Document (in-memory DOM). JAXB allows that. After this, you can manipulate the document any way you wish, adding or removing parts.

I wrote some filters that whitelist or blacklist fields (in XSD they are elements) and classes (in XSD they are complex types). While I see a lot of potential problems with this approach, it did the job in my case. Below is the code for case 2 schema:

```
// This SchemaOutputResolver implementation saves XSD into DOM
static class DOMResultSchemaOutputResolver extends SchemaOutputResolver  {

    private List<DOMResult> results = new LinkedList<DOMResult>();

    @Override
    public Result createOutput(String ns, String file) throws IOException {
      DOMResult result = new DOMResult();
      result.setSystemId(file);
      results.add(result);
      return result;
    }

    public Document getDocument() {
      return (Document)results.get(0).getNode();
    }

    public String getFilename() {
      return results.get(0).getSystemId();
    }

}

  // This method serializes the DOM into file
  protected void serializeXsdToFile(Document xsdDocument, String filename) throws IOException {
    OutputFormat format = new OutputFormat(xsdDocument);
    format.setIndenting(true);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(os, format);
    serializer.serialize(xsdDocument);
  }

  @Test
  public void generateSchema2() throws JAXBException, IOException, XPathExpressionException {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(RootNode.class);
    DOMResultSchemaOutputResolver schemaOutputResolver = new DOMResultSchemaOutputResolver();

    context.generateSchema(schemaOutputResolver);

    // Do your manipulations here as you want. Below is just an example!
    filterXsdDocumentComplexTypes(schemaOutputResolver.getDocument(), asList("childNodeA"), true);
    filterXsdDocumentElements(schemaOutputResolver.getDocument(), asList("fieldB"));

    serializeXsdToFile(schemaOutputResolver.getDocument(), "xf.xsd");
  }

  private boolean shouldComplexTypeBeDeleted(String complexTypeName, List<String> complexTypes, boolean whitelist) {
    return (whitelist && !complexTypes.contains(complexTypeName)) || (!whitelist && complexTypes.contains(complexTypeName));
  }


  protected void filterXsdDocumentComplexTypes(Document xsdDocument, List<String> complexTypes, boolean whitelist) throws XPathExpressionException {
    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    NodeList complexTypeNodes = (NodeList)xPath.evaluate("//*[local-name() = 'complexType']", xsdDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < complexTypeNodes.getLength(); i++) {
      Node node = complexTypeNodes.item(i);
      Node complexTypeNameNode = node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name");

      if (complexTypeNameNode != null) {
        if (shouldComplexTypeBeDeleted(complexTypeNameNode.getNodeValue(), complexTypes, whitelist)) {
          node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);
        }
      }
    }

    NodeList elements = (NodeList)xPath.evaluate("//*[local-name() = 'element']", xsdDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.getLength(); i++) {
      Node node = elements.item(i);
      Node typeNameNode = node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("type");
      if (typeNameNode != null) {
        if (shouldComplexTypeBeDeleted(typeNameNode.getNodeValue(), complexTypes, whitelist) && !typeNameNode.getNodeValue().startsWith("xs")) {
          node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  protected void filterXsdDocumentElements(Document xsdDocument, List<String> blacklistedElements) throws XPathExpressionException {
    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    NodeList elements = (NodeList)xPath.evaluate("//*[local-name() = 'element']", xsdDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.getLength(); i++) {
      Node node = elements.item(i);
      if (blacklistedElements.contains(node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue())) {
        node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);
      }
    }
  }
```